# how do i create a list from csv contents and then search within that list

Tags: python, list, csvreader

im trying to read a csv file in python, then save the contents of csv file into list so that i can then search within that list to see if it matches the input from the user.

here is what i have so far . my code keeps skipping to the else block even if the input matches the number in csv file.

data = []

```
with open ("numbers.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

if input in data:
   print("success")

else: 
   print("no match")
```

Comment: Your [mre] should always include an example of the data. In this case several lines of `numbers.csv`. `if input in data:` - `input` is a built-in python function it is unlikely that function will be in your csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
data = df.values.tolist()

if input in data:
   print("success")

else: 
   print("no match")
```